# javascript function - return value chain

Tags: javascript

I need to access local variable returned by function inside a chained function

ex.

```
$("#history_table").bind("sortStart", function() {
     var a=30;
     return a;
}).bind("sortEnd", function() {
     alert(a);               
});
```

here in this example I need to access variable a returned by the first function, sortStart and aortEnd events will trigger the two functions asynchronously...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable needs to be declared outside:

```
var a = 0;
$("#history_table").bind("sortStart", function() {
     a=30;
     return a;
}).bind("sortEnd", function() {
     alert(a);               
});
```

or make it as property of the current object using the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function:

```
$("#history_table").bind("sortStart", function() {
     var a = 30;
     $(this).data('a', a);
     return a;
}).bind("sortEnd", function() {
     var a = $(this).data('a');
     alert(a);               
});
```

Comment: I think the `.data()` approach is the one that makes sense. Returning a value from an event handler - even a "custom" event handler - really doesn't make much sense, unless the idea is explicitly to control bubbling in some dynamic way.